# Pure css submenu vertical

Tags: html, css

I got a css3 menu with this code:

HTML:

```
<div id="navi">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">First</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Second</a>
            <ul class="child">
                <li><a href="#">First child</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Third</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#navi {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}
#navi ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
#navi ul li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
#navi ul li a {
    line-height: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    border: thin solid #999;
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #0CF;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s;
    -ms-transition: all 1s;
    -o-transition: all 1s;
    transition: all 1s;
}
#navi ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #0C3;
}
#navi ul li ul {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition: height 1s linear 0s;
    -moz-transition: height 1s linear 0s;
    -ms-transition: height 1s linear 0s;
    -o-transition: height 1s linear 0s;
    transition: height 1s linear 0s;
    height: 0px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#navi ul li:hover ul {
    height: 100px;
    -webkit-transition: height 1s linear 0s;
    -moz-transition: height 1s linear 0s;
    -ms-transition: height 1s linear 0s;
    -o-transition: height 1s linear 0s;
    transition: height 1s linear 0s;
}
```

Fiddle [`Here`](http://jsfiddle.net/q4fjV/)

Now I want that the menu isn't horizontal. It should be vertical. I tried to remove `float:left;` but then the submenu doesn't display. The submenu should press all menu items below down. Any suggestions? Would be great.

Comment: why don't you use accordion for this with jquery

Comment: I don't know jQuery. But every suggestion (even with jQuery) is welcome. I will have a look at every suggestion :)

Comment: you want to open submenu by pussing down the other main nav elements ? or on it's right side

Comment: If you press menu item "second" it should open the submenu. And then all menu items below (here: menu item "Third") should be go down so the submenu has some space to display. You know what I mean?

Comment: if you like to learn more you can try them. http://tympanus.net/codrops/tag/menu/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do this, it will give it perfect look and push your `nav` three item down. Add this height to your particular class:

```
#navi ul li:hover ul {
    height:32px;
}
```

But if you have other sub menu items in other main `nav` items with different items in them, then you should make classes for all particular elements and give them height according to them. Have a look at this:

```
#navi ul li:hover .class {
    height:64px; /*for two items in sub menu and like this for other*/ 
}
```

Comment: It will work but can be done by changing the positioning of submenu :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
#navi {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}
#navi ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
#navi ul li {

}

#navi ul li a {
    line-height: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    border: thin solid #999;
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #0CF;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s;
    -ms-transition: all 1s;
    -o-transition: all 1s;
    transition: all 1s;
}
#navi ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #0C3;
}
#navi ul li ul {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: height 1s linear 0s;
    -moz-transition: height 1s linear 0s;
    -ms-transition: height 1s linear 0s;
    -o-transition: height 1s linear 0s;
    transition: height 1s linear 0s;
    height: 0px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#navi ul li:hover ul {
    height: 100px;
    -webkit-transition: height 1s linear 0s;
    -moz-transition: height 1s linear 0s;
    -ms-transition: height 1s linear 0s;
    -o-transition: height 1s linear 0s;
    transition: height 1s linear 0s;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="navi">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">First</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Second</a>
            <ul class="child">
                <li><a href="#">First child</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Third</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Check this

Comment: Yeah but why is the whole menu going so big? **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FhFya/)**

Answer (score 0):

your css:

```
#navi {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}
#navi ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
#navi ul li {
    position: relative;
}
#navi ul li a {
    line-height: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    border: thin solid #999;
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #0CF;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s;
    -ms-transition: all 1s;
    -o-transition: all 1s;
    transition: all 1s;
}
#navi ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #0C3;
}
#navi ul li ul {
    position:absolute;
    -webkit-transition: height 1s linear 0s;
    -moz-transition: height 1s linear 0s;
    -ms-transition: height 1s linear 0s;
    -o-transition: height 1s linear 0s;
    transition: height 1s linear 0s;
    height: 0px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#navi ul li:hover ul {
    position:absolute;
    left: 100px;
    top: 0px;
    height:50px;
    -webkit-transition: height 1s linear 0s;
    -moz-transition: height 1s linear 0s;
    -ms-transition: height 1s linear 0s;
    -o-transition: height 1s linear 0s;
    transition: height 1s linear 0s;
}
```

your html:

```
<div id="navi">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">First</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Second</a>
            <ul class="child">
                <li><a href="#">First child</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Third</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

copy and paste this coding. its worked. i think you want like this vertical menu bar???

Comment: No the submenu shouldn't display on menu item's right. but thanks for help :)